# How to reset model data on view load

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Lets say I have a users Model

```
export interface Users {
    user_id:number;
    email: string;
    forename:string;
    surname:string;
    username:string;
    dob:Date;
    telephone:string;
}
```

And I have some mock data for it

```
import { Users } from '../../models/Users';
let list: Users[] = [
    {
        user_id:1,
        email: 'test@tester.com',
        forename:'Joe',
        surname:'Bloggs',
        username:'Joe',
        dob:new Date,
        telephone:'0151111111',
    }
];

export let userList = list;
```

And I am importing the users model into my ts file and storing it in a variable like this

```
import { userList } from '../../mocks/Users/Users';
import { Users } from '../../models/Users';

let usersList: Users[] = userList;
```

If I then edited my newly created `usersList` variable, like so

```
this.usersList[1].email = 'newemail@test.com';
```

How would i actually reset this variable back to the original mock data when the view loads? At the moment whenever I navigate away from the page and come back to it, the `newemail@test.com` is persistant, but each time the page loads, I want to be able to reset it back to the original mock data email of `test@tester.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that return an array.

```
import { Users } from '../../models/Users';

export const createUserList = (): User[] => [
    {
        user_id:1,
        email: 'test@tester.com',
        forename:'Joe',
        surname:'Bloggs',
        username:'Joe',
        dob:new Date,
        telephone:'0151111111',
    }
];
```

In your component

```
let usersList: Users[] = createUserList();
```

Comment: Array is new here, but link to object is left, so changes will left.
You need to add JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mockData));

Comment: This works brilliantly! Is this the best practise to achieve my goal? Is there an initial way to code the model, data and component to remove this issue, or is this the way it has to be done everytime? Thanks

Comment: @Vayrex it returns a new array everytime, I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @S_R it is one of the best practices, but I don't know if it is the best one. Definitely the easiest and simplest one though. You can also make a static class if you want, or export an utils object.

Comment: @trichetriche ok brilliant, thanks again, great simple answer!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help !